# MongoDB Seeding Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a MongoDB where I am seeding the data of the DB from JSON files. The JSON files are structured correctly and the seed file is mostly working. The issue I am having is that the nested array of objects is getting seeded with only the Mongo ID and not the whole object. I have tried a number of collection functions (`collection.insert(), collection.save(), ...`) but they all return the same thing.

Here is what the data should look like, where projects are the nested array of objects:

```
{
    "client_name": "2017 Colorado Hospital Association",
    "projects": [
      {
        "project_name": "2017 Project",
        "p_number": "CHA201652",
        "hours_used": 356.03,
        "approved_hours": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is what is being returned:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "5ae8d05b5ee3f79bfdefd357"
  ],
  "_id": "5ae8d05b5ee3f79bfdefd39d",
  "client_name": "2017 Colorado Hospital Association",
  "__v": 0
},
```

So here is my seed.js file:

```
// Require DB Models
const db = require('./models');
const clientList = require('./data/client.json');
const userList = require('./data/user.json');
const projectList = require('./data/projects.json');

// SEEDING THE DB
db.User.remove({}, (err, users) => {
  console.log('Removed All Users');
  db.User.create(userList, (err, users) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('DB User creation err: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Created User DB!');
  });
});

db.Project.remove({}, (err, projects) => {
  console.log('Removed Projects');
  db.Project.create(projectList, (err, projects) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('DB Project Creation Err: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Created Project DB!');

    // Client Creation
    db.Client.remove({}, (err, clients) => {
      console.log('Removed All Clients');
      clientList.forEach((clientData) => {
        let client = new db.Client({
          client_name: clientData.client_name,
          projects: []
        });
        // console.log('client data: ', clientData);
        clientData.projects.forEach((projectData) => {
          // console.log('project data: ', projectData);
          db.Project.findOne({p_number: projectData.p_number}, (err, foundProject) => {
            if(err) {
              console.log('Find Project Err: ', err);
            }
            // console.log('found project: ', foundProject);
            client.projects.push(foundProject);
            // console.log('client post push: ', client);
            client.save((err, savedClient) => {
              if(err) {
                console.log('Save Client Err: ', err);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The Project.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    project_name: String,
    p_number: String,
    hours_used: Number,
    approved_hours: Number,
    remaining_hours: Number
});

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);

module.exports = Project;
```

The Client.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Project = require('./project');

const ClientSchema = new Schema({
  client_name: String,
  projects: [
    {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project '}
  ]
});

// MODEL
const Client = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);

// EXPORT
module.exports = Client;
```

And my index.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/client-portal');

module.exports.Client = require('./client');
module.exports.User = require('./user');
module.exports.Project = require('./project');
```

I have looked over a number of stack questions in regards to this and the `$set` has not worked, since it is having to find all the projects by the p_number and then associate it to the client.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: So what's the problem here? Items not being created in the other "related" collection? That's how it works. MongoDB is not relational and mongoose won't "do it for you" either. If you want items in a different colllection, then you need to explicitly insert them "in that collection". All putting the full object in the parent array does is insert the reference `ObjectId`. Not the whole object, and not creating an item in another collection.

Comment: @NeilLunn didn't realize that Mongo just made references to the DB objects when a Schema has another Schema in it. Thanks